# What are these bugs wiggling white fluffy hats?

Tags: species-identification

Seen yesterday (October 10) in Southern Ontario (near Muskoka), near a lake. Maybe 0.5cm in size or so, during the afternoon.

Hundreds of these little bugs seem to be holding or attached to a curly white piece of fluff each and swinging them back and forth wildly.

What are these? And what are they doing?

Video: https://i.imgur.com/t7kWyKr.mp4

Image (image sucks, please see video): [image]

Comment: My research suggests the Woolly Aphid or the Beech Blight Aphid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not very particular but I think they are Beech blight aphid(*Grylloprociphilus imbricator*)

Beech blight aphid is a small insect in the order Hemiptera.The aphids form dense colonies on small branches and underside of leaves.[image]

You can get more info https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beech_blight_aphid